# Java Printing all of my maps keys and values

Tags: java, hashmap

Quick question and its probably the most simple answer but i need to print a textual representation of my `HashMaps` contents.

My code so far is:

```
public void printAll() {
    Set< String> Names = customersDetails.keySet();
    Collection< CustomerDetails> eachCustomersNames = customersDetails.values();
    for (String eachName : Names) {
        System.out.println(eachName)
    }
    for (CustomerDetails eachCustomer : eachCustomersNames) {
        System.out.println(eachCustomer);
    }
}
```

But this results in the list of keys and then a list of values but i need each line of text to read something like

Bob [example]

Where Bob is the key and example is the value.

Comment: `customersDetails.toString()` ? This requires that your `CustomerDetails` class has implemented `toString()`.

Comment: Stick to the Java Naming Conventions! `Names` should be `names`!

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Java 8, you can take advantage of lambda syntax and `.forEach()` like so:

```
customersDetails.forEach((k,v) -> {
    System.out.println(k + "[" + v + "]");
});
```

Where `k` is your key and `v` is the value tied to key `k`.

Answer (score 0):

Every key maps to just one value, so you can just do this:

```
Set < String> Names = customersDetails.keySet();

for (String eachName: Names) {
    System.out.println(eachName + " [" +  customersDetails.get(eachName).toString() + "]")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using Java 8, simply print both key and value for each key:

```
for (String eachName : Names) {
    System.out.println(eachName + " [" + customersDetails.get(eachName) + "]");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael this worked a treat, some things are so simple and yet your mind thinks its hard!

Answer (score 0):

You can print your Map like so :

```
Map<String, String> customersDetails = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : customersDetails.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey()  + '[' + entry.getValue() + ']');
}
```

If you are using java 8 you can use :

```
customersDetails.entrySet().forEach((entry) -> {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey()  + '[' + entry.getValue() + ']');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start dealing with maps with more complicated types consider using [ReflectionToStringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43719640/java-printing-all-of-my-maps-keys-and-values). Internally it uses reflection to build a string of an object and its fieldd. It recurses through the object graph too.

It may not be efficient, but it helps a lot with debugging and printing operations.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate over your keys/values in order to print your map, as the `HashMap.toString()` method already does this for you very efficiently (actually, it's the `AbstractMap.toString()` method).

If you have your `CustomerDetails` class implement the `toString()` method, then you only need to do:

```
System.out.println(customerDetails);
```

And this will print your map in the format you require.